# Logistic regression in R, basing on which class(0 or 1) in dependent variable the modelling is performed

Tags: r, classification, logistic

In R and in binomial logistic regression to be specific, the modelling is based on which class amongst 0 and 1? And if it builds model based on 1 by default, is there a parameter or something in which we can pass 0 so that the model is built basing on class 0?

At least this is what I percieve, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I've heard that in SAS, modelling is done based on class 1 rather than class 0(Is it true?). So I was curious to know how it works in R.

Comment: I think you should study logistic regression a bit more. Your question doesn't make sense to me in this context. Anyway, it is off-topic here and I'm voting to have ot moved to the appropriate Stackexchange site.

Comment: You can specify the outcome as `glm(I(youroutcome == 0) ~`

Comment: I don't understand why the question got closed on crossvalidated. Other than being a bit unclear, I don't see anything wrong with it. I suspect user is asking if R uses 1 as baseline level in logistic regression.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear with the above explanation and extremely sorry for posting it twice, I thought of posting it here so that this question might reach more users and I can get the answer quickly. @Roman, Exactly... I wanted to know what is the baseline level or "reference category" which is given by user in multinomial logistic regression and if the response is ordinal, usually the highest or the lowest category in ordinal scale is chosen. But "what will be the baseline in binomial logistic regression?" is my question. Thanks in advance. Sorry if someone is still missing clarity.

Comment: What about this two links? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282048/logistic-regression-defining-reference-level-in-r https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-epi/2010-October/000232.html

Comment: You should be able to pick which way you want the model to be built, whether on 0's or on 1's.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: It was closed on CV because there's no statistical content - setting the reference category for a factor to use as the response in R's `glm` function counts as "performing routine operations within a statistical computing platform". I'm not sure why the version on SO was migrated here.

Comment: @Scortchi I will agree that this is a borderline case. Given that setting a reference category in logistic regression is something someone doing statistics will encounter, in which case CV is a logical place to look.